# Converting a single column of a BufferedImage into a new BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I want to take a BufferedImage (in this case it is 3600x3600) and take the first column of pixels and create a new BufferedImage out of that (creating an image 1x3600), here is the code I have:

```
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageUtilities.readImageFile("C:/someImage.png");
int[] columnData = new int[originalImage.getHeight()];
originalImage.getRGB(0, 0, 1, originalImage.getHeight(), columnData, 0, 1);
BufferedImage columnImage = new BufferedImage(1, originalImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
WritableRaster raster = columnImage.getRaster();
raster.setPixels(0, 0, 1, originalImage.getHeight(), columnData);
```

But I keep getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3600
    at java.awt.image.SinglePixelPackedSampleModel.setPixels(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.WritableRaster.setPixels(Unknown Source)
```

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X I feel like I've played with all the indices that might be a zero-index to no luck, any insights?

Comment: `originalImage.getSubimage(0, 0, 1, img.getHeight());` - Now, I'd be tempted to "paint" the result to a new `BufferedImage` as the *"The returned `BufferedImage` shares the same data array as the original image."* (quoted from the JavaDocs)

Comment: Use `setRGB` instead of `setPixels` - there seems to be a difference in exception over what the arrays hold

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *[Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html)* class to copy an area of an image.

Here is an example.
I'm using the following image.
*https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2309/STSCI-HST-abell370_1797x2000.jpg*.

Here is the *JavaDoc* for the *drawImage* method.
*[Graphics#drawImage (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,java.awt.image.ImageObserver))*.

```java
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("STSCI-HST-abell370_1797x2000.jpg"));
int w = 1, h = 2000;
BufferedImage cropped = new BufferedImage(w, h, image.getType());
Graphics g = cropped.createGraphics();;
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, w, h, null);
g.dispose();
ImageIO.write(cropped, "jpg", new File("STSCI-HST-abell370_cropped.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [@MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer), I ended up using `artwork.getSubimage(0,0,1,artwork.getHeight())`, which did the trick!